# Wordpress conditional statements not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm setting up some conditional statements to change my page layout for different pages. My first conditional says

```
if (is_page('15030')) {
}
```

The content inside that one is for the homepage, and works perfectly. Then my next one says

```
elseif (is_page('Sales')){
}
```

And it doesn't work at all. I've tried using the page name, page ID, changing elseif to if, using in_category - nothing is showing up at all. Any idea what I should look for that could cause that? I noticed that I set up "sales" as a category of posts, and when I created the Sales page, it is automatically showing the posts from the sales category, which is what I wanted, but I'm not sure if that would be affecting it at all?

The code is located in custom_functions.php. Here is the complete code:

```
function custom_template() {
if (is_page('15030')) : ?>
    <!--Technology Section-->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post_box top">
            <a class="scroll" id="technology"></a>
            <div class="left">
                <a href="index.php?page_id=15174"><img src="../../../images/businessbee/blog/tech-bubble.gif" alt="Technology" class="bubble"/></a>
                <h3><a href="index.php?page_id=15174">Technology</a></h3>
                <p>Technology upgrades don't have to break the bank. From improving your hardware to streamlining your IT management, we've compiled cost-effective solutions to cover your needs. </p>
                <hr/>
                <ul class="catCount">
                    <?php
                        $catList = wp_list_categories('title_li=&show_count=1&echo=0&child_of=3527&hide_empty=0');
                        $catList = preg_replace('@\<li([^>]*)>\<a([^>]*)>(.*?)\<\/a>@i', '<li$1><a$2><span class="name">$3</span></a>', $catList);
                        $catList = ereg_replace('</a> \(([0-9]+)\)', ' <span class="count">\\1</span><br class="clear"/></a>', $catList);
                        echo $catList;
                    ?>
                    <br class="clear"/>
                </ul>
                <hr/>
                <a href="index.php?page_id=15174" class="allLink">View all Technology Resources</a>
            </div><!--left-->
            <div class="right">
                <h4>Featured Resources</h4>
                    <?php global $post; ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                        <?php query_posts('cat=3527'); ?>
                       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                <a href="<?= the_permalink() ?>" class="box">
                                  <div class="thumbnailBox">
                                    <h3><?= the_title()?>
                                    <span>posted in <?= $categories[0]->cat_name; ?></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div><!--right-->
            <br class="clear"/>
            <img src="../../../images/businessbee/blog/page-div.png" alt="" class="blog-page-div"/>

            <!--SALES SECTION-->
                <a class="scroll" id="sales"></a>
                <div class="left">
                    <a href="index.php?page_id=15206"><img src="../../../images/businessbee/blog/sales-bubble.gif" alt="Sales" class="bubble"/></a>
                    <h3><a href="index.php?page_id=15206">Sales</a></h3>
                    <p>Every sales team needs a solid method for tracking leads and identifying its top performers. Take a look at these great resources, designed to help maximize your conversion rate.</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <ul class="catCount">
                    <?php
                        $catList = wp_list_categories('title_li=&show_count=1&echo=0&child_of=3536&hide_empty=0');
                        $catList = preg_replace('@\<li([^>]*)>\<a([^>]*)>(.*?)\<\/a>@i', '<li$1><a$2><span class="name">$3</span></a>', $catList);
                        $catList = ereg_replace('</a> \(([0-9]+)\)', ' <span class="count">\\1</span><br class="clear"/></a>', $catList);
                        echo $catList;
                    ?>
                        <br class="clear"/>
                    </ul>
                    <hr/>
                    <a href="index.php?page_id=15206" class="allLink">View all Sales Resources</a>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                <h4>Featured Resources</h4>
                    <?php global $post; ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                        <?php query_posts('cat=3536'); ?>
                       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                <a href="<?= the_permalink() ?>" class="box">
                                  <div class="thumbnailBox">
                                    <h3><?= the_title()?>
                                    <span>posted in <?= $categories[0]->cat_name; ?></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div><!--right-->
            <br class="clear"/>
            <img src="../../../images/businessbee/blog/page-div.png" alt="" class="blog-page-div"/>

    </div><!-- post id div-->
    </div><!--content-->

<!--End of Homepage Content-->

     elseif (is_page('Sales')){
        <h2>Test Content</h2>
    }

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you please post the code where this is located?

Comment: Sure @DavidChase - updated above.

Comment: watch those open and close `php` tags :)

Comment: Yeah I'm not very good at recognizing when to use them

Comment: take a look at my answer and see if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its needs to be `if` instead of `elseif` and wrapped in php tags like so

```
<?php endif; ?> // this closes the 1st if statement aka the if for is_page('15030').

<?php if ( is_page('Sales') ): ?>
<h2>Test Content</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Seems like it should work, but it isn't. The category pages seem completely resistant to any kind of conditional targeting. I have conditional statements that are adding a body class, and that works fine, but even if I use a conditional statements outside of the custom template function to add something in another part of the site, the page isn't recognizing it's category, ID or anything

Comment: try `is_category()` instead of `is_page` its takes "Category ID, Category Title, Category Slug or Array of IDs, names, and slugs". source: [**is category function**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. The pages will respond to a custom loop, but I don't think I want to use that to control the entire page display.

Comment: is Sales a page/post or category or some other taxonomy?

Comment: I have a sales category set up, and a sales page. When I opened up the sales page, it was automatically showing all posts labeled sales. I didn't expect that to happen, but it was actually the end result that I was looking for, so I didn't look into it. However I need to show more on the page than just the posts, which is why I'm trying to edit the custom template. To save some time, I already tried switching is_category() to is_archive(), and I double checked to make sure the page was set to use the custom template.

Comment: did you make this custom template or custom_functions.php and did you put/move `<?php endif; ?>` on top of your `is_page('Sales')` instead on the bottom as it currently appears in the code you posted. because that code is meant to show only on the home page

Comment: Yes I made the custom_functions.php - I'm working with the Thesis theme, so everything is going into custom_functions.php. The endif is moved so there is an endif then the new if for the sales page, then another end if

Answer (score 0):

According to the Codex:

> Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call  wp_reset_query() after The Loop.

It looks to me like you *are* using it inside the loop.